# adding a style to all TD elements of table

Tags: css, coldfusion

I am trying to add a style="vertical-align:top" to all the td elements of the table. Trying this will coldfusion, following this post but could not able to make it work

http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Removal-and-tags-around-data

[coldfusion add an id to certain classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771913/coldfusion-add-an-id-to-certain-classes)

Comment: "not able to make it work" is very ambiguous. Please post your code and a description of how the results differed from what you expected, including any error messages.

Comment: I don't think doing this server-side is the appropriate approach here. You need to give more detail as per @Leigh's observation. We are not telepathic, so cannot tell why things might not work, how "not working" manifests itself, and what you consider the difference between "working" and "not working" is. I think perhaps you ought to read this, and take the advice onboard: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/need-help-know-how-to-ask-for-it.html

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason why you are trying to apply this style with ColdFusion? Why not just apply the style in your stylesheet?

```
table tr td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: because the styles are getting ignored here so doing the traditional way

Comment: @twistermetal - can you explain how they are being ignored? Not trying to tell you how to code your solution, it's just that the additional information can lead to other relevant answers.

Comment: @twistermetal have a look with something like chrome's inspect element, then you can see if your style is being overtaken by something else, what it is ( and where its coming from ) ... just an idea! :)

Comment: If you give your table an ID, then you can reference it directly in the CSS: table#myID tr td . . .

Answer (score 2):

You need a semi colon at the end
        `<td style="vertical-align:top;">your content here</td>`

this would also work: 
        `<td valign="top">Your content here</td>`